# How to Show Home Icon and Centered Text in actionbar

Tags: android

I m developing an android app and i want to display icon in the left and title at centered. when i trying to title in centered the the activity icon is not showing. Please tell me the solution. Where I m wrong.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.center_action_bar_text, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        /*actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.center_action_bar_text);*/
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText("abc");
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_go);
        tab.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("abc");
        tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_search);
        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("abc");
        tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_go);
        tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this code ##

**create a layout file custom_actionbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_icon"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And your java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    // Custom actionbar

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    LayoutInflater actionbarLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View actionbarView = actionbarLayoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView appName = (TextView) actionbarView
            .findViewById(R.id.app_title);
    ImageView appLogo = (ImageView) actionbarView
            .findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

    appName.setLayoutParams(lp);
    appName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    actionBar.setCustomView(actionbarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

}
```